# What is the correct result of resolving a promise with itself

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, bluebird, q

[Here is
 a promise](https://github.com/JOE-XIE/MyWheel/blob/master/MyPromise/6.%E8%BE%BE%E5%88%B0promiseA%2B%E8%A7%84%E8%8C%83/mypromise.js) that passed the [promises-aplus-tests](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests).If I run below code, then nothing will show in the console. But if I change to use node.js Promis it will show **'catch Chaining cycle detected for promise'**.
Are they both ok? Or just promises-aplus-tests missing this test case?

As [Promises/A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/) says

> 2.3.1 If promise and x refer to the same object, reject promise with a TypeError as the reason.

```
var myPromise = new MyPromise (function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(myPromise);
    }, 0);
});
myPromise.then(function (value) {
    console.log('then',value);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('catch',err.message);
});
```

[Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) log the same as node.js;
[Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) log the anonymous function

```
function (resolve) {  
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(myPromise);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: "*[Here is a promise](https://github.com/JOE-XIE/MyWheel/blob/f3b2ec18c0623e1a43d3a34a961fe25b4d575524/MyPromise/6.达到promiseA%2B规范/mypromise.js) that passed the promises-aplus-tests.*" - ouch, that code is horrible, it has many race conditions. Promise/A+ tests don't catch everything.